# jQuery form validation validate age

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working on a form that is validated through jQuery form validation. I am wondering if there is any existing jQuery or javascript to validate that a person is at least 16 years old. One requirement is that the form can not be submitted if the user is not at least 16 years old.

I know this validation is not enough, so there will be some server side validation as well.

Comment: I believe the jQuery validation plugin allows you to define your own custom validation functions, and then use them to validate fields. Comparing two dates - one entered using a datepicker for their D.O.B and the current date - to determine if the difference is at least 16 years shouldn't be too difficult. You should be able to find all the information you need to do this in other questions on SO, I think. I'm not familiar enough with jQuery validation to help myself, unfortunately.

Comment: I think the pre-built number validation might have a min/max option. That'll work only if the user is putting in an integer though.

Comment: Are you simply asking the age?  Are you asking for birthdate?  You're going to have to show your code both for the jQuery and HTML, and explain what data you're collecting if you want a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [the plugin's `addMethod()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), there is no limit to what you can accomplish with this plugin.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element, params) { 
    // your custom validation function
    // return false; // represents failed validation
    // return true; // represents passed validation
}, jQuery.format("failed - your custom message"));
```

The arguments to the callback are:

- the current **value** of the validated element
- the **element** to be validated
- **parameters** specified for the method, e.g. for `min: 5` the parameter is `5`, for `range: [1, 5]` its `[1, 5]`

There are several ways you can apply the new rule.  The standard way would just be to declare it inside `.validate()` along with your other rules.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // other options
        rules: {
            myfield1: {
                required: true,
                myRule: true // true/false or parameters
            },
            // other rules,
        }
    });

});
```

See this working demo where I made a custom rule.  You can enter anything except a "5".

**http://jsfiddle.net/kKhFJ/**